# Looking for grep commands to pass to linux servers

Tags: grep

Is there a way to grep or ls -l from a Linux server and it return any file or directory that has extended attributes?

I will be using BladeLogic to pass the command to target servers and collecting the information for processing into a results table within Blade.

Answer (score 2):

The command you are searching for is

```
 lsattr -R /directory/to/be/searched
```

From the Linux manual (`man lsattr`) for `lsattr`:

```
NAME
       lsattr - list file attributes on a Linux second extended file system

SYNOPSIS
       lsattr [ -RVadv ] [ files...  ]

DESCRIPTION
       lsattr lists the file attributes on a second extended file system.  See
       chattr(1) for a description of the attributes and what they mean.

OPTIONS
       -R     Recursively list attributes of directories and their contents.
```

This is the output of this command, as unprivileged user, in my home directory.

```
$ lsattr -R | more
-------------e-- ./zz.txt 
-------------e-- ./VirtualBox VMs

./VirtualBox VMs:
-------------e-- ./VirtualBox VMs/Ollie2

./VirtualBox VMs/Ollie2:
-------------e-- ./VirtualBox VMs/Ollie2/Ollie2.vbox
-------------e-- ./VirtualBox VMs/Ollie2/Ollie2.vbox-prev
-------------e-- ./VirtualBox VMs/Ollie2/Logs

./VirtualBox VMs/Ollie2/Logs:
-------------e-- ./VirtualBox VMs/Ollie2/Logs/VBox.log
-------------e-- ./VirtualBox VMs/Ollie2/Logs/VBox.log.1
-------------e-- ./VirtualBox VMs/Ollie2/Logs/VBox.log.2
-------------e-- ./VirtualBox VMs/Ollie2/Logs/VBox.log.3

-------------e-- ./VirtualBox VMs/Ollie2/Ollie2.vdi

-------------e-- ./VirtualBox VMs/JH

./VirtualBox VMs/JH:
-------------e-- ./VirtualBox VMs/JH/JH.vbox-prev
-------------e-- ./VirtualBox VMs/JH/JH.vbox
-------------e-- ./VirtualBox VMs/JH/JH.vdi
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This actually worked, sort of, but it did not provide me with any attributes.  Here's what I ran and the output:

lsattr -R /home |more
-------------   /home/wec1234/my_file

Comment: @jerzdevs see my post

Answer (score -1):

**Very simple**, go to the suspect folder and run the command:

lsattr -laR | grep +immutable